# Add an assembly to GAC without using command prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-prompt, gac, gacutil

- Hi all,

  can anyone tell me how can i add an assembly to the GAC **without
  using Visual Studio Command Prompt**?Is there a manual way like copy
  and pasting? I know that using **gacutil -i AssemblyName** command in
  the command prompt i can do this.But i need an other way to do
  this.Any ideas?

  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without using gacutil, may be you can try creating folder structure as mentioned below and copy your assembly there,
c:\Windows\assembly\(YourAssemblyName)\(FullVersion)(PublicKeyToken)
Finally copy YourAssemblyName.dll to the above folder.

Comment: I would advise against this. That folder structure is internal to the GAC and should not be used directly. They also differ from .Net version to .Net version.

Comment: @LarsTruijens Thanks that you pointed out the usage of `new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish().GacInstall("YourAssemblyName.dll");`. I never came across this..

Answer (score 2):

Installers, like [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/), are the way to go if you want to deploy your application.

I am not sure why you don't want to use the command prompt, but if you are looking on how to do it in code you could use the method GacInstall from the [System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.internal.publish.aspx) class.

```
new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish().GacInstall("YourAssemblyName.dll");
```

If you need more control you should look at the [GAC](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/317540)/[Fusion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404523.aspx) API. See [here](http://powershellgac.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PowerShellGac/PowerShellGac/GlobalAssemblyCache.cs) for an example written in C# for a PowerShell module controlling the GAC.

If all you want is a tool other than gacutil, then please use one that does use the proper APIs and does not manipulate the folder structure directly. Like [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/dot_net_tools/gac_viewer.html) one for example.